# How Can I put a error msg if there is a blank field on Java?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a unit converter and it seems its working i just need to give them an error if they don't put any number on the first field and other error if they put a number on the second field (so they cant convert it backwards)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editCentimeters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCentimeters);

        final EditText editInches = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editInches);

        Button buttonConvert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);

        buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                double centimeters = Double.valueOf( editCentimeters.getText().toString());

                double inches = centimeters *  0.393700787 ;

                editInches.setText(String.valueOf(inches));

            }
        });



    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use  [`Toast`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) for this purpose.

Comment: editinches should b a textview so that user can't edit or add any value... Next use should do a check if editcentimeter is empty, if yes you display an error... Can be Alertdialog, toast to show the error message

Comment: According to the modern guidelines, it's preferable to use `Snackbar` instead of a `Toast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setError() method for this. do somthing like this

```
buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(editCentimeters.getText().toString().equals("")){

                 editCentimeters.setError("*Field Required");

             }else{

            double centimeters = Double.valueOf( editCentimeters.getText().toString());

            double inches = centimeters *  0.393700787 ;

            editInches.setText(String.valueOf(inches));

           }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Toast to give a error message.
But I use EditText.setError() method. So user will be able see exactly which field is responsible for validation problem
Click [HERE for a tutorial](http://droid-blog.net/2012/05/15/two-simple-ways-to-make-your-users-aware-of-incorrect-input/) and [Here for another solid tutorial](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-show-error-in-edittext/).

This is a sample code (I do not have ADT in here, so forgive me if it needs some correction):

```
        final EditText editCentimeters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCentimeters);
        final EditText editInches = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editInches);




        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        boolean isValid = true;
        if (editCentimeters.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            editCentimeters.setError("This input cannot be null");
            isValid = false;
        }
        if (editInches.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            editInches.setError("This input cannot be null");
            isValid = false;
        }

        if (isValid) 
        {           
            double centimeters = Double.valueOf( editCentimeters.getText().toString());

            double inches = centimeters *  0.393700787 ;

            editInches.setText(String.valueOf(inches));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check the value inside each `EditText` yourself, and notify the user if its empty:

```
buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(!"".equals(editCentimeters.getText().toString())) {
            // If the field is not empty, proceed to calculation
            double centimeters = Double.valueOf( editCentimeters.getText().toString());
            double inches = centimeters *  0.393700787 ;
            editInches.setText(String.valueOf(inches));
        } else {
            // If it's empty, show a message to the user)
            editCentimeters.setError("This field can not be empty");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The Toast class will be suitable for this purpose as:-

```
if(editText.getText().toString().equals(""))
   Toast.makeText(this,"Your Error msg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The first argument is the Context of your Activity

Second is the CharSequence
And third is the duration of the Toast.

Answer (score 0):

editinches should b a textview so that user can't edit or add any value... Next use should do a check if editcentimeter is empty, if yes you display an error... Can be Alertdialog, toast to show the error message.

```
if(editcentimeter.isEmpty(){
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new    AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Missing value");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Please enter a value");

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Please enter a numbert!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dismiss();
                }
              });
        }
}
```